# How do I escape brackets character with ANTLR 4

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I want to eliminaite '(' and ')' from TEXT. How can I escape '(' and ')'?
( and \\( didn't work.

I want '(' and ')' to be recognized as operator for decision priority.

```
grammar Query;

// Parser

query: expr+ ;

expr: NOT expr
  | expr AND? expr
  | expr OR expr
  | REGEXP
  | TEXT
  | STRING
  | LPAREN expr RPAREN
  ;


// Lexer

LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;

AND: 'AND' ;
OR: 'OR' ;
NOT: 'NOT' ;

TEXT : ~[()\n\r" ]+ ;
STRING : '"' ('""'|~'"')* '"' ; // quote-quote is an escaped quote
REGEXP : '/' (~'/')* '/' ; // quote-quote is an escaped quote
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

This return follows

```
» grun Query query -tree
(A AND B) OR C
(query (expr (expr ( (expr (expr A) AND (expr B)) )) OR (expr C)))
```

I needs

```
(query (expr (expr (expr (expr A) AND (expr B) )) OR (expr C)))
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved this problem by not lexer and parser. 
It is a problem how listener process a parse result.